# Form tags and queries

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby

I've been working on a problem for a while and I feel like my solution should be right, but it keeps giving me "freeze; end" error.

I am doing a restaurant search and I am trying to let users set parameters to help narrow down the restaurants they want.

Below is my html code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<%= form_tag home_path do %>
  <%= label_tag(:cuisine, "Cuisine:" %>
  <%= text_field_tag (:cuisine) %>

  <%= label_tag(:zipcode, "Zipcode:" %>
  <%= text_field_tag (:zipcode) %>

  <%= label_tag(:lower, "lowerScore:" %>
  <%= text_field_tag (:lower) %>

  <%= label_tag(:higher, "higherScore:" %>
  <%= text_field_tag (:higher) %>

  <%= submit_tag("Search") %>
<% end %>

<% @my_search.each do|search| %>
<%= search.name %>
  <% end %>

</body>
</html>
```

and in my welcomes_controller in the def home:

```
@my_search = Restaurant.joins(:inspection).where(cuisine: params[:cuisine], zipcode: params[:zipcode], totalscore: params[:lower..:higher])
```

Why am I receiving errors from this?

Thank you for everyone's help so far, I think its all coming together now

Comment: You have a syntax error here `params[:cuisine}`

Comment: oops. I actually fixed this in my code but didnt update. I'll do it now. There is still a weird error though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

please change this

```
 @my_search = Restaurant.joins(:inspection).where(cuisine: params[:cuisine}, zipcode: params[:zipcode], totalscore: params[:lower..:higher])
```

to this

```
@my_search = Restaurant.joins(:inspection).where(cuisine: params[:cuisine], zipcode: params[:zipcode], totalscore: params[:lower..:higher])
```

secondly this label_tag does not seem right. where is the end of this (

for example change this

```
label_tag(:cuisine, "Cuisine:"
```

to this

```
label_tag :cuisine, "Cuisine:"
```

Comment: oh my. that was very silly. I can't believe i did that. Thank you so much, I think I'm sleep deprived right now and thats why I'm making such careless mistakes.

Comment: On a side note - don't add a space between the method and the parens `text_field_tag (:higher)`. This is a matter of style but it definitely makes it easier to read. If there is a space than it looks like you are trying to wrap an argument in parens instead of the method evocation. eg `foo (1+2)`